# Banach fixed-point theorem : Existence of solution

Tags: systems-of-equations, fixed-point-theorems

We have the system \begin{align*}&x_1=\left (5+x_1^2+x_2^2\right )^{-1} \\ &x_2=\left (x_1+x_2\right )^{\frac{1}{4}}\end{align*} and the set $G=\{\vec{x}\in \mathbb{R}^2: \|\vec{x}-\vec{c}\|_{\infty}\leq 0.2\}$ where $\vec{c}=(0.2,1)^T$.

I want to show with the Banach fixed-point theorem that the system has a solution in $G$.

I have done the following:

Let \begin{equation*}\Phi (x_1, x_2)=\begin{pmatrix}\left (5+x_1^2+x_2^2\right )^{-1} \\ \left (x_1+x_2\right )^{\frac{1}{4}}\end{pmatrix}\end{equation*} The jacobi matrix is \begin{equation*}\nabla \Phi =\begin{pmatrix}-\frac{2x_1}{(x_1^2+x_2^2+5)^2} & -\frac{2x_2}{(x_1^2+x_2^2+5)^2} \\ \frac{1}{4(x_1+x_2)^{\frac{3}{4}}} & \frac{1}{4(x_1+x_2)^{\frac{3}{4}}} \end{pmatrix}\end{equation*}

Then we get \begin{equation*}\|\nabla \Phi \|_{\infty}=\max \left \{\frac{2x_1+2x_2}{(x_1^2+x_2^2+5)^2}, \frac{1}{2(x_1+x_2)^{\frac{3}{4}}}\right \}\end{equation*}

We want to get an upper bound for that, don't we?

How can we do that? Could you give me a hint?

Comment: Is it for homework or research?

Comment: I am trying to solve some exercises by self for practice @Surb

Comment: I can not use my second hand at the moment... so cant write answer (too long). Still, it should be quite easy to show that both quantities in the max are $<1$. Indeed for $(x_1,x_2)\in G$ you have $0\leq x_1 \leq 0.4$ and $0.8 \leq x_2 \leq 1.2$

Comment: For that we have to use $\|\vec{x}-\vec{c}\|_{\infty}\leq 0.2$ or not? But I still don't see how. @Surb

Comment: yes the maximum is taken over $G$. To apply the banach fixed point theorem take $(G,\|.\|_\infty)$ as metric space (if you can show that $\Phi(G)\subset G$)

Comment: I got stuck right now. Could you explain that further to me? @Surb

Comment: As said, not really at the moment (writing with one hand is tooo annoying). If nobody has answered by tomorrow, I'll do so.

Comment: Don't forget to show that this function actually maps $G$ to (some subset of) $G$.

Comment: How could we do that? Could you give me a hint? @jmerry

Comment: For each coordinate of $\Phi$, how big and how small can it get? It's much like the derivative calculations, just easier in general.

Comment: @MaryStar I wrote down a quite full solution. Sorry, it is not a hint but as you seemed still blocked after the hints of yesterday, I thought it may good to write things down so that you understand how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that 
$$G = \{(x_1,x_2)\mid \|(x_1,x_2)-(0.2,1)\|_{\infty}\leq 0.2\} =\{(x_1,x_2)\mid |x_1-0.2|\leq 0.2 \text{ and } |x_2-1|\leq 0.2\} \\= [0,0.4]\times [0.8,1.2].$$
Now, let 
$$\phi_1(x_1,x_2)=(5+x_1^2+x_2^2)^{-1}\quad\text{ and }\quad \phi_2(x_1,x_2)=(x_1+x_2)^{1/4},$$
so that $\Phi(x_1,x_2)=(\phi_1(x_1,x_2),\phi_2(x_1,x_2))$.

For $(x_1,x_2)\in G$ it holds 
$$0\leq \phi_1(0.2,1.2)\leq \phi_1(x_1,x_2)\leq \phi_1(0,0.8)\approx 0.1773\leq 0.4$$
and
$$0.8 \leq 0.9457\approx \phi_2(0,0.8)\leq \phi_2(x_1,x_2)\leq \phi_2(0.2,1.2)\approx 1.0878 \leq 1.2$$
It follows that $\Phi(G)\subset G$.

Now, in order to apply the Banach fixed point theorem, you want to show that $\Phi$ is a strict contraction on $(G,\|\cdot\|_{\infty})$, i.e. there exists $\alpha <1$ such that 
$$\|\Phi(x)-\Phi(y)\|_{\infty}\leq \alpha \|x-y\|_{\infty},\qquad \forall x=(x_1,x_2),y=(y_1,y_2)\in G.\tag{1}$$
Let $x,y\in G$. As $\Phi$ is differentiable on $G$, by MVT, there exists 
$s,t\in [0,1]$ such that $u=s x+(1-s)y$ and $v=t x+(1-t)y$ satisfy 
$$(x-y)\cdot\nabla \phi_1(u) = \phi_1(x)-\phi_1(y)\quad\text{and}\quad (x-y)\cdot\nabla \phi_2(v) = \phi_2(x)-\phi_2(y).$$ 
Hence, if we can show that there exists $\alpha<1$ independent of $x,y$ such that
$$|(x-y)\cdot\nabla \phi_1(u)|\leq \alpha \|x-y\|_{\infty}\quad\text{and}\quad |(x-y)\cdot\nabla \phi_2(v)|\leq \alpha \|x-y\|_{\infty},$$ 
then, $\alpha$ satisfies $(1)$ and we are done. Now, note that
$$\max\{|(x-y)\cdot\nabla \phi_1(u)|,|(x-y)\cdot\nabla \phi_2(v)|\}\leq \max\{\|\nabla\Phi(u)(x-y)\|_{\infty},\|\nabla\Phi(v)(x-y)\|_{\infty}\}\\ \leq \max\{\|\nabla \Phi(u)\|_{\infty,\infty},\|\nabla \Phi(v)\|_{\infty,\infty}\} \|x-y\|_{\infty}$$
where 
$$\|\nabla \Phi(z)\|_{\infty,\infty}=\max_{\|w\|_{\infty}\leq 1}\|\nabla\Phi(z)w\|_{\infty}.$$
Furthermore, as $u,v\in G$, combining the above arguments, we deduce that we can set
$$\alpha = \max_{z\in G}\|\nabla \Phi(z)\|_{\infty,\infty}.$$
Now, for $z\in G$, we have,
$$\|\nabla \Phi(z)\|_{\infty,\infty}=\max\{\|\nabla \phi_1(z)\|_{1},\|\nabla \phi_1(z)\|_{1}\},$$
and you have computed that 
$$\|\nabla \phi_1(z)\|_{1}=\frac{2z_1+2z_2}{(z_1^2+z_2^2+5)^2}, \qquad\text{and}\qquad\|\nabla \phi_2(z)\|_{1}=\frac{1}{2(z_1+z_2)^{3/4}}.$$
As $z\in G=[0,0.4]\times [0.8,1.2]$, we find that 
$$\frac{2z_1+2z_2}{(z_1^2+z_2^2+5)^2}\leq\frac{2(0.4+1.2)}{(0^2+(0.8)^2+5)^2}\approx 0.1006 \leq 0.2$$
$$\frac{1}{2(z_1+z_2)^{3/4}}\leq \frac{1}{2(0+0.8)^{3/4}}\approx 0.5911 \leq 0.6$$
Therefore, we conclude that with $\alpha=0.6$,
$$\|\Phi(x)-\Phi(y)\|_{\infty}\leq 0.6 \|x-y\|_{\infty}$$
which implies that $\Phi\colon G\to G$ is a strict contraction with respect to $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$ and thus, as $(G,\|\cdot\|_{\infty})$ is a complete metric space, the Banach fixed point theorem implies that $\Phi$ has a unique fixed point $p\in G$. Furthermore, for every $x\in G$, the iterative sequence $\Phi^k(x)$ converges towards $p$. A simple numerical experiments shows that 
$$p = (0.163190947349524, 1.049361520947913)$$

Comment: Ahh ok!! I got it!!! Thank you!! Using the Fix point iteration with initial approximation $\vec{x}^{(0)}=\vec{c}$ we get: 
\begin{equation*}\vec{x}^{(k+1)}=\Phi (\vec{x}^{(k)})\end{equation*} 

\begin{equation*}\vec{x}^{(1)}=\Phi (\vec{x}^{(0)})=\Phi (0.2, 1)=\begin{pmatrix}\left (5+0.2^2+1^2\right )^{-1} \\ \left (1+0.2\right )^{\frac{1}{4}}\end{pmatrix}\approx \begin{pmatrix} 0.165563\\ 1.046635\end{pmatrix}\end{equation*}

Comment: Using the Newton method we get: \begin{align*}\vec{x}^{(1)}&=\vec{x}^{(0)}-\left (\nabla \Phi (\vec{x}^{(0)})\right )^{-1}\Phi (\vec{x}^{(0)})=\begin{pmatrix}0.2 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix}-0.01096 & -0.054822 \\ 0.134500 & 0.2180490 \end{pmatrix}^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}\left (5+0.2^2+1^2\right )^{-1} \\ \left (1+0.2\right )^{\frac{1}{4}}\end{pmatrix} \\ & =\begin{pmatrix}0.2 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix}-0.01096 & -0.054822 \\ 0.134500 & 0.2180490 \end{pmatrix}^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}0.16556 \\ 1.046635\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-18.5568 \\ 7.76981\end{pmatrix}\end{align*}

Comment: Why do we get such a big difference at the result? Or is the result of the Newton method wrong?

Comment: Well, assuming that newton converges (which still needs a proof), then it may be that your equation $\Phi(x)=x$ has more than one solution on $\Bbb R^2$ and Newton method converges to one of these other solutions for the starting point you are using. Certainly $(-18,7)\notin G$, and you can not say much about the convergence of Newton after only one iteration. What your second example essentially shows is that the Newton iteration can not be expected to stay in $G$ when started in $G$. That's all.

Comment: Do you mean that it is possible that we start with a point in $G$ the results of the next iterations will not be in $G$ and then we get again results in $G$ ?

Comment: @MaryStar I can not say this is not the case, but this is not a question about the original post and you should then ask a new question about the convergence of Newton's method.